# Javascript textbox need to become visible based of combobox

Tags: javascript

Hello Guys I'm just wondoring if my `and` operator is correct because this code below works

```js
if (x == "stud0") {
  document.getElementById("school").style.visibility = "visible";
} else {
  document.getElementById("school").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

And when I add the `and` operator below it does not work. Does anyone can give me a hand sorry I'm new in javascript

```js
if (x == "stud0") && (x == "stud1") && (x == "stud2") {
  document.getElementById("school").style.visibility = "visible";
} else {
  document.getElementById("school").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: You need to put all the conditions inside the same parenthesis. `if(x == "stud0" && x == "stud1" && x == "stud2")`

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your conditions to `()` in `if` statement and use OR `||` in conditions:

```
if ((x == "stud0") || (x == "stud1") || (x == "stud2")) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark answers as solutions if they helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x === "stud0" && x === "stud1" && x === "stud2"){
                      document.getElementById("school").style.visibility="visible";
 }
else{
                    document.getElementById("school").style.visibility="hidden";
  }
```

Try it. You should usually compare value with === operator in js